# How can I get my delete button to actually delete the name and the checkbox next to it?

Tags: java, arraylist, jbutton, actionlistener, jcheckbox

**I'm trying to get my program for user to check a checkbox with a name next to it and then be able to delete the whole row (from arrayList) when pressing the delete button.** My program will look something like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.TextField;

public class ManageUsersGUI1 extends JPanel {
    public static ArrayList<AddUsers> users = new ArrayList<>();

    private JLabel addNewUserLabel;
    private JTextField addNewUserTextField;
    private JLabel deleteUsersLabel;
    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private JPanel namePanel;

    public ManageUsersGUI1() {
        //construct components
        addNewUserLabel = new JLabel ("Add new User here:");
        addNewUserTextField = new JTextField (0);
        deleteUsersLabel = new JLabel ("Select which User(s) you would like to delete:");
        addButton = new JButton ("Add");
        deleteButton = new JButton ("Delete");
        namePanel = new JPanel();
        namePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(namePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        //set components properties
        addNewUserTextField.setToolTipText ("Enter name and click on Add button.");
        addButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to Add new user.");
        deleteButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to delete User(s) selected.");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (580, 485));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (addNewUserLabel);
        add (addNewUserTextField);
        add (deleteUsersLabel);
        add (namePanel);
        add (addButton);
        add (deleteButton);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        addNewUserLabel.setBounds (85, 130, 120, 25);
        addNewUserTextField.setBounds (235, 130, 125, 25);
        deleteUsersLabel.setBounds (135, 225, 281, 25);
        addButton.setBounds (385, 130, 100, 25);
        namePanel.setBounds(225, 270, 140, 0);
        deleteButton.setBounds (230, 335, 100, 25);

        addButton.addActionListener(new AddButtonListener());

        deleteButton.addActionListener(new DeleteButtonListener());


    }

    private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = addNewUserTextField.getText();
            users.add(new AddUsers(text));

            // Display the charges.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text + " has been added.");

            JCheckBox nameCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
            nameCheckBox.setText(addNewUserTextField.getText());
            namePanel.add(nameCheckBox);
            namePanel.setBounds(225, 270, 140, namePanel.getHeight() + 25);
            deleteButton.setBounds(230, deleteButton.getY() + 25, 100, 25);
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) getRootPane().getParent();
            frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() + 25);
            frame.pack();
        }
    }

    private class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ///STUCK HERE///   
         }
    }      


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("AddUsersPanel1");
        frame.setTitle("Manage Users");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new ManageUsersGUI1());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

AddUsers code:

```
public class AddUsers{

   private String userName;

   public AddUsers(String userName) {
      this.userName = userName;
   }

   public AddUsers() {
      userName = "";
   }   

   public void setUserName(String userName) {
      this.userName = userName;   
   }

   public String getUserName() {
      return userName;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return userName + "\n";
   }

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your functionality. These are compiler errors. You are using variables that you haven't declared. ´users` isn't declared  at all, and `nameCheckBox` is a local variable in `AddButtonListener`, but you are trying to use it in `DeleteButtonListener`.

Comment: I did not know how to get those checkboxes to remove with the string that was inputted along with it because it is set up the way it is through the JPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudo code

1. Iterate over all
   children to obtain a reference to one child at a time
2. Check if
   the child is an instanceof JCheckBox
3. If yes, confirm the check
   box child is ticked (checked)
4. If yes invoke `namePanel.remove(child);`
5. When you are done removing all eligible
   children, call `revalidate();` and `repaint();` (in that order) on the
   name panel to ensure the UI is refreshed properly

Here's my finished code:

```
private class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(Component component : namePanel.getComponents()) {
           if(component instanceof JCheckBox) {
              if(((JCheckBox)component).isSelected())
                 namePanel.remove(component);
           }
        }
        namePanel.revalidate();
        namePanel.repaint();
     }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can successfully add the JComponents to the screen then the following should help:

```
 add(myComponent);
 //your component should be there, if not you may call 
 /*repaint()*/
 //then when you want to remove, call
 remove(myComponent);
 //remember that you need to actually properly set the text for the JComboBox items.
```

Comment: I have already successfully added everything from the textfield into my program when clicking add. I am not trying to get a JComboBox but rather I just want to be able to remove the items including the checkbox when I press delete according to the names I selected. It is not a JComboBox....

Comment: can't you invoke remove on the components that you want to remove?
Try calling repaint(); after, or revalidate();

Comment: The problem is I have no idea how to invoke the components so that it takes out the names from the arraylist. Everytime I try to put nameCheckBox under the DeleteButtonListener it says they can't find the symbol and I even tried to put the             `JCheckBox nameCheckBox = new JCheckBox();` as a field and it does not work.

Comment: You don't know how to remove items from an ArrayList?
users.remove(Object o) ? Then refresh your list? I'm sorry I haven't had time solve your problem! I'm really just not understanding what your problem is

Comment: i get how to remove it from the ArrayList but I want to remove the JCheckBox with it too. I don;t even know how to reword this. I don't get how to invoke it because the nameCheckBox isn't found when i write it under the DeleteButtonListener. Then I try making the JCheckBox a field and it doesn't work either.